# Pandas - Calculate row values based on prior row value, update the result to be the new row value (and so on)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

#### Below is some dummy data that reflects the data I am working with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

random.seed(30)

# Dummy data that represents a percent change
datelist = pd.date_range(start='1983-01-01', end='1994-01-01', freq='Y')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"P Change_1": np.random.uniform(low=-0.55528, high=0.0396181, size=(11,)),
                   "P Change_2": np.random.uniform(low=-0.55528, high=0.0396181, size=(11,))})
#This dataframe contains the rows we want to operate on
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Loc1': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 2.5415], 
    'Loc2': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 3.2126],})

#Set the datetime index
df1 = df1.set_index(datelist)
df2 = df2.set_index(datelist)
```

#### df1:

```
            P Change_1  P Change_2
1984-12-31   -0.172080   -0.231574
1985-12-31   -0.328773   -0.247018
1986-12-31   -0.160834   -0.099079
1987-12-31   -0.457924    0.000266
1988-12-31    0.017374   -0.501916
1989-12-31   -0.349052   -0.438816
1990-12-31    0.034711    0.036164
1991-12-31   -0.415445   -0.415372
1992-12-31   -0.206852   -0.413107
1993-12-31   -0.313341   -0.181030
1994-12-31   -0.474234   -0.118058
```

#### df2:

```
              Loc1    Loc2
1984-12-31     NaN     NaN
1985-12-31     NaN     NaN
1986-12-31     NaN     NaN
1987-12-31     NaN     NaN
1988-12-31     NaN     NaN
1989-12-31     NaN     NaN
1990-12-31     NaN     NaN
1991-12-31     NaN     NaN
1992-12-31     NaN     NaN
1993-12-31     NaN     NaN
1994-12-31  2.5415  3.2126
```

#### DataFrame details:

First off, Loc1 will correspond with P Change_1 and Loc2 corresponds to P Change_2, etc. Looking at Loc1 first, I want to either fill up the DataFrame containing Loc1 and Loc2 with the relevant values or compute a new dataframe that has columns Calc1 and Calc2.

#### The calculation:

I want to start with the 1994 value of Loc1 and calculate a new value for 1993 by taking Loc1 1993 = Loc1 1994 + (Loc1 1994 * P Change_1 1993).  With the values filled in it would be 2.5415 +(-0.313341 * 2.5415) which equals about 1.74514.

This 1.74514 value will replace the NaN value in 1993, and then I want to use that calculated value to get a value for 1992.  This means we now compute Loc1 1992 = Loc1 1993 + (Loc1 1993 * P Change_1 1992).  I want to carry out this operation row-wise until it gets the earliest value in the timeseries.

What is the best way to go about implementing this row-wise equation?  I hope this makes some sense and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is in every case only last  and single row's value  present in df2?

Comment: So far that is the case with this dataset.  It will always have a single value but in some cases that value is in 1993 or 1995, so it may not always be in the same place.

Comment: I think you want something like this https://imgur.com/a/Pn4sX0W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', right_index=True, left_index=True)   # merging dataframes on date index
df['count'] = range(len(df))    # creating a column, count for easy operation


# divides dataframe in two part, one part above the not NaN row and one below
da1 = df[df['count']<=df.dropna().iloc[0]['count']]  
da2 = df[df['count']>=df.dropna().iloc[0]['count']]


da1.sort_values(by=['count'],ascending=False, inplace=True)
g=[da1,da2]
num_col=len(df1.columns)

for w in range(len(g)):
    list_of_col=[]
    count = 0
    list_of_col=[list() for i in range(len(g[w]))]
    for item, rows in g[w].iterrows():
        n=[]
        if count==0:
            for p in range(1,num_col+1):
                n.append(rows[f'Loc{p}'])
        else:
            for p in range(1,num_col+1):
                n.append(list_of_col[count-1][p-1]+  list_of_col[count-1][p-1]* rows[f'P Change_{p}'])
        list_of_col[count].extend(n)
        count+=1
    tmp=[list() for i in range(num_col)]
    for d_ in range(num_col):
        for x_ in range(len(list_of_col)):
            tmp[d_].append(list_of_col[x_][d_])
    z1=[]
    z1.extend(tmp)
    for i in range(num_col):
        g[w][f'Loc{i+1}']=z1[i]

da1.sort_values(by=['count'] ,inplace=True)
final_df = pd.concat([da1, da2[1:]])

calc_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(num_col):
    calc_df[f'Calc{i+1}']=final_df[f'Loc{i+1}']
print(calc_df)
```

I have tried to include all the obscure thing I have done in the comment. I have edited my code to let initial dataframes remain unaffected.

[Edited] : I have edited the code to include any number of columns in the given dataframe.

[Edited:]If the name of columns are arbitrary in df1 and df2, please run this block of code **before** running the upper code. I have renamed the columns name using list comprehension!

```
df1.columns = [f'P Change_{i+1}' for i in range(len(df1.columns))]
df2.columns = [f'Loc{i+1}' for i in range(len(df2.columns))]
```

Comment: This is great and works how I expect!  Although, now I am wondering if there is a more convenient way to do this to handle 50 columns of data in each DataFrame without explicitly calling the column names?  Is there a way to restructure my DataFrame column headers beforehand to link the two DataFrames beforehand and then just loop through and do the row-wise operation one column at a time?  Thank you again for your response!

Comment: @JeffColdplume if you want  like say 50 or more columns,  in both dataframe, I can tweak the code.Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, my real dataset has about 50 columns in each dataframe.  That is my bad for not mentioning that in my question.  I am more than happy to open another question for that, if it helps at all.

Comment: No need for that, it will be repetition. Let me try, just a little change in this code will do what you need.

Comment: @JeffColdplume This is a sample of output for a dataframe containing 5  columns with arbitrary names in df1 and df2  https://imgur.com/a/5LFf9yP , I hope this does what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: The only issue left is if I had a start value in 1993 (in the Loc1 column)  that I was extrapolating from.  It raises this error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds  on this line of code: ---> 21 da1 = df[df['count']<=df.dropna().iloc[0]['count']]

Comment: @JeffColdplume sorry, I didn't understand very well ,  are you trying to say  that this code doesn't work on a dataframe ,that is similar to  the dataframe given in question ,and gives an error!

Comment: @JeffColdplume also note that the code you have given in the question doesn't generates **df1** and **df2** as you have shown in question, it generates a **df1** and **df2** like this ,https://imgur.com/a/jH8JxsF , in which df2 has values in rows corresponding to 1993 and not 1994!

Comment: It just wasn't working when the non-nan value for one column was in 1994 and in the other column the first non-nan value was 1993. But you have answered my question well and I will try and work out a fix for this.  I really do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED] Perhaps there are better/more elegant ways to do this, but this worked fine for me:

```
def fill_values(df1, df2, cols1=None, cols2=None):
    if cols1 is None: cols1 = df1.columns
    if cols2 is None: cols2 = df2.columns

    for i in reversed(range(df2.shape[0]-1)):
        for col1, col2 in zip(cols1, cols2):
            if np.isnan(df2[col2].iloc[i]):
                val = df2[col2].iloc[i+1] + df2[col2].iloc[i+1] * df1[col1].iloc[i] 
                df2[col2].iloc[i] = val

    return df1, df2

df1, df2 = fill_values(df1, df2)

print(df2)

    Loc1    Loc2
1983-12-31  0.140160    0.136329
1984-12-31  0.169291    0.177413
1985-12-31  0.252212    0.235614
1986-12-31  0.300550    0.261526
1987-12-31  0.554444    0.261457
1988-12-31  0.544976    0.524925
1989-12-31  0.837202    0.935388
1990-12-31  0.809117    0.902741
1991-12-31  1.384158    1.544128
1992-12-31  1.745144    2.631024
1993-12-31  2.541500    3.212600
```

This assumes that the rows in df1 and df2 corresponds perfectly (I'm not querying the index, but only the location). Hope it helps!

Comment: If in df2, if some random row's **Loc1** and **Loc2** is not NaN , instead of last rows, does you code work then? It probably seems to give error, can you check that?

Comment: What makes you think it might give an error? I tested it, and it seems to work fine. I added some random value in the middle (specifically at index "1989-12-31", Loc1) and no errors (it left that value alone and computed the rest correctly) :-)

EDIT: try add this before my code (but after your code): df2.Loc1.iloc[5] = 3;
df2.Loc2.iloc[3] = 3.14

Comment: what if in given dataframe **df2** in question,  last row's **Loc1** and **Loc2** were NaN, does it work then?

Comment: You mean that you wouldn't have any values at all? Let me check.

EDIT: Okay, I see what you're saying. Let me look into it! It raises an error if the first values are NaN. My bad.

Comment: after operating the code in question, I did some tweaks in df2 column as shown in https://imgur.com/a/cq7CzQE  , after that I ran your code and it gives error!

Comment: I edited the implementation above, hopefully it works now! I changed reversed(range(df2.shape[0])) to reversed(range(df2.shape[0]-1))

Comment: After doing the same thing what I have shown in the link in my previous comment, the ouptput comes as https://imgur.com/a/CDSqNZ7 .

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, what you need is `Loc1[year]=Loc1[next_year] + PChange[year]*Loc1[next_year]`, right?
The below loop will do what you are looking for, but it just assumes that the number of rows in both df's is always equal, etc. (instead of matching the value in the index). From your description, I think this works for your data.

```
for i in range(df2.shape[0]-2,-1,-1):
    df2.Loc1[i]=df2.Loc1[i+1] + (df1.PChange_1[i]*df2.Loc1[i+1])
```

Hope this helps :)